# Connecting ArcMap to Oracle DB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, oracle-dbms, database, query-layer

I am trying to establish a connection from ArcMap 10.0 -- Service Pack 5 to an Oracle DB (I thought it was 10g if might be 11g) on windows 7.. It is windows  have connected to the database via Catalog. However, I keep getting an error when trying to add query layer. I have attached a picture for more context. Any ideas as to why?
If I try to connect via oracle 11g it says failed to connect to the specified server. Underlying DBMS error.

[image: arcmap screen grab]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the ***exact*** versions of ArcGIS and Oracle Database Server involved, as well as the exact Oracle client(s) installed on the GIS workstation. Have you checked the support pages for compatibility? You should always include the full error message **as text**, so it is legible on all devices, and searchable by others.

Comment: There are a few disturbing things in the info provided: the fact that you connect to Oracle 10g. That is no longer supported - unless you are on the lastest 10g patch (something like 10.2.0.6 if memory serves me). The other is that the screen shot looks like WinXP ? You definitely need to provide the exact version numbers of all the components involved as Vince suggested.

Comment: The other disturbing thing is in the list of databases on the right, that lists tables belonging to the CTXSYS schema. Those are internal tables used by the full text search facility. A regular user should not see those and definitely not have access to that schema at all. The fact that they are visible may indicate that the connection "EGSDS.odc" uses a highly privileged user to connect, which is not really good: it opens a security risk and misuse or human error can lead to serious trouble.